# How to define @Input as FormControl?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "form-component",
  template: ``
})
export class FormComponent {

  @Input() userInput?: string;

}
```

and now I want to convert the member `userInput` (I always make Input bindings optional, because they might not be used) to a `FormControl` by writing:

```
@Input() userInput = new FormControl("");
```

or does this conflict with the binding mechanism in any way? 
Regarding to the types, this seems not a good practice, because `userInput` is not a `string` anymore.

**My question**

How do I property assign a `@Input` binding to a `FormControl`?

**Suggestion**

Might it be necessary to assign the (probably) bound value in onInit like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "form-component",
  template: ``
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() userInput?: string;
  userControl: FormControl;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userControl = new FormControl(this.userInput ? this.userInput : "");
  }

}
```

Comment: You can declare any type as Input parameter. A form control type implements an AbstractControl and this what should be pass. Notice that it is an object and changeDetection will do deep spying for this case and this has a performance cost

Comment: Ok, but when i declare my input parameter to be type of `FormControl`, then I have to pass in a `FormControl`, right? Or does Angular map a bound `string` to the `FormControl`s value property?

Comment: You are right. You will have to create and move formControl which is an implementation of abstract control.You can define your input parameter as abstractControl and move a formControl to it.
Angular will not translate string to formControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that type of input is a string. So I would bind it like you have done in your suggestion. But I would do it on change instead of onInit.

```
 ngOnChanges() {
    this.userControl = new FormControl(this.userInput ? this.userInput : "");
  }
```

I cannot think why you would create the FormControl somewhere else and pass it as an input.

Comment: I don't want to create the FormControl somewhere else. This would be bad practice. I just want to map an @Input binding to a FormControl.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way:

```
@Component({
  selector: "form-component",
  template: ``
})
export class FormComponent {
  @Input()
  set userInput(v: string){
    this.userControl.setValue(v || "");
  }
  userControl: FormControl = new FormControl("");    
}
```

Depending on how you are planning to use this component, it might be even better to implement the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface.

Comment: I am planning to use this component as a create/edit component. Your approach saves the ngOnInit, + for this.

Comment: So it will basically wrap an input field or input group?

Comment: Yes, basically this is my intention.